# Trying to use longtable

Tags: longtable

thanks for your help. I'm trying to pass this table into longtable and I really don't get how to do it, if anyone can help me. This is my graduation proyect and is my first time working with LaTeX. I'm using TeXstudio. Here is a capt of my result and the code.

```
\begin{longtable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{3.5cm}}
        \hline
        \centering Proceso principal & \centering Sub-proceso & \centering Conocimiento & \centering Mejoras con DM &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering Técnica} \\
        \hline

        \centering Evaluación & \multirow{4}{*}{\centering Evaluación del Estudiante} & \parbox[l][0.6\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Patrones de éxito o fracaso de estudiantes en un curso en específico
                \item Patrones de éxito de estudiantes con alto rendimiento en un curso en específico
            \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Agrupamiento de estudiantes con éxito o fracaso en un curso en específico
            \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Clasificación
            \end{itemize} } \\ \cline{3-5}
%fin primera
            && \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Patrones de éxito o fracaso de estudiantes para graduarse
                    \item Predicción de la tasa de graduandos                   
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Predicción del porcentaje de estudiantes que se graduarán o no
                    \item Predicción de la tasa de graduandos cada semestre
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Predicción, Clustering
                    \item Predicción
                \end{itemize} } \\ \cline{3-5}
%fin segunda
            && \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Patrones de estudiantes con bajo rendimiento
                    \item Patrones característicos de estudiantes con alto rendimiento
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Predicción de probabilidad de éxito
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Predicción
                \end{itemize} } \\ \cline{3-5}
%fin tercera
            && \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Patrones de estudiantes de acuerdo a sus calificaciones
                    \item Asociación de las calificaciones con la información personal de los estudiantes
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Asociación de la información personal del estudiante con la calificación
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[l][0.5\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Asociación
                \end{itemize} } \\
%fin primera parte
        \hline

        \centering Desempeño & \multirow{4}{*}{\centering Desempeño del Estudiante} & \parbox[p][0.3\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con su Promedio Académico Acumulativo
            \end{itemize} } & \parbox[p][0.3\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con su Promedio Académico Acumulativo
            \end{itemize} } & \parbox[p][0.3\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Asociación
            \end{itemize} } \\ \cline{3-5}
%finprimera
        &&  \parbox[p][0.4\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con la planificación del curso
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[p][0.4\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con la planificación del curso (tiempo del curso)
                \end{itemize} } & \parbox[p][0.4\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Asociación
                \end{itemize} } \\ \cline{3-5}
%finsegunda
        &&      \parbox[p][0.4\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Patrones de éxito de estudiantes de alto rendimiento que presentan bajo Promedio Académico Acumulativo
                    \end{itemize} } & \parbox[p][0.4\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Predicción de probabilidad de estudiantes de alto rendimiento que presentan bajo Promedio Académico Acumulativo
                    \end{itemize} } & \parbox[p][0.4\textwidth][l]{4cm}{
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Predicción
                    \end{itemize} } \\ 
%finsegundaparte            

        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Principales procesos de la Minería de Datos en EDM. Fuente: Delavari (2005)}
        \label{ta:tabla1}
    \end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Just `longtable`, you shouldn't have `tabular` within `longtable`, instead, where you have `tabular` you should replace them with `longtable`. The `table` environment, which I assume you had before, sets up a float and is for your captions and list of tables and stuff. The `tabular` environment is the one for the actual table itself and that's what you need to convert to `longtable`. I *think* you need to get rid of `table` altogether

Comment: P.S. there's actually nothing stopping you from putting an image or even just some ordinary text within a `table` environment. Obviously that'd be a bizarre thing to do in most cases, but it makes the point, I think :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\compress\vspace{-2ex}
                       \RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\vspace*{-2ex}}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]\centering
\caption{Principales procesos de la Minería de Datos en EDM. Fuente: Delavari (2005)}
    \label{ta:tabla1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc*{2}{P{5.25cm}}P{2.5cm}@{}}
        \toprule
\thead{PP\textsuperscript{*}} 
    &   \thead{SP\textsuperscript{**}} 
        &   \thead{Conocimiento} 
            &   \thead{Mejoras con DM} 
                &  \thead{Técnica}          \\
        \midrule
\multirow{30}{*}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Evaluación}}
    &   \multirow{30}{*}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Evaluación del Estudiante}} 
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Patrones de éxito o fracaso de estudiantes en un curso en específico
            \item Patrones de éxito de estudiantes con alto rendimiento en un curso en específico
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Agrupamiento de estudiantes con éxito o fracaso en un curso en específico
                \end{itemize}  
                &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                    \item Clasificación
                    \end{itemize}       \\ 
        \addlinespace
%fin primera
    &&  \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
        \item Patrones de éxito o fracaso de estudiantes para graduarse
        \item Predicción de la tasa de graduandos
        \end{itemize}  
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Predicción del porcentaje de estudiantes que se graduarán o no
            \item Predicción de la tasa de graduandos cada semestre
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Predicción, Clustering
                \item Predicción
                \end{itemize}               \\ 
    \addlinespace
%fin segunda
    &&  \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
        \item Patrones de estudiantes con bajo rendimiento
        \item Patrones característicos de estudiantes con alto rendimiento
        \end{itemize}  
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Predicción de probabilidad de éxito
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Predicción
                \end{itemize}           \\ 
    \addlinespace
%fin tercera
    &&  \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
        \item Patrones de estudiantes de acuerdo a sus calificaciones
        \item Asociación de las calificaciones con la información personal de los estudiantes
        \end{itemize}  
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Asociación de la información personal del estudiante con la calificación
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Asociación
                \end{itemize}           \\
%fin primera parte
    \midrule
\multirow{15}{*}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Desempeño}} 
    & \multirow{15}{*}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Desempeño del Estudiante}}
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con su Promedio Académico Acumulativo
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con su Promedio Académico Acumulativo
                \end{itemize}  
                &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                    \item Asociación
                \end{itemize}       \\ 
    \addlinespace
%finprimera
    &&  \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
        \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con la planificación del curso
        \end{itemize}  
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Asociación del desempeño del estudiante con la planificación del curso (tiempo del curso)
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Asociación
                \end{itemize}           \\ 
    \addlinespace
%finsegunda
    &&  \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
        \item Patrones de éxito de estudiantes de alto rendimiento que presentan bajo Promedio Académico Acumulativo
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Predicción de probabilidad de estudiantes de alto rendimiento que presentan bajo Promedio Académico Acumulativo
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Predicción
                \end{itemize}       \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textsuperscript{*}  Proceso principal, \quad
                       \textsuperscript{**} Sub-proceso}
%finsegundaparte
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Your table I was able to fit into one page, so the `longtable` is not necessary. Also I made some modification in table layout that its look nicer and have more space for your itemizing.

[image]

Added fram is only for show page layout. In real use you had to omit option `showframe` in package `geometry`.

**Addendum: use of longtable**

In case that you will realy need a `longtable`, than you need consider @Au101 comments. Long table is complete table system  In it you cannnot nested tabular environments on the way as you did (it can be nested in particular cells, if this is necessary for some reason). However, part of `longtable` are captions (main, on continuation of table in the next page(s)).

In design of `longtable` you need to

- define/design the `firsthead`, `head`, `firstfoot` and `foot`
- put caption of table into `firstfoot` (for details see code below)
- content in should be set on the same way as in `tabular.

Relevant part of code for your table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            justification=centerlast]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{continued}{#1\hfill(cont.)}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\compress\vspace{-2ex}
                       \RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\vspace*{-2ex}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}cc*{2}{P{5.25cm}}P{2.5cm}@{}}
\caption{Example of long table. For final form of table it have to be complied at list twice.}
    \label{ta:tabla1}                       \\
    \toprule
\thead{PP\textsuperscript{*}}
    &   \thead{SP\textsuperscript{**}}
        &   \thead{Conocimiento}
            &   \thead{Mejoras con DM}
                &  \thead{Técnica}          \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\captionsetup{textformat =continued}
\caption{Principales procesos de la Minería de Datos en EDM. Fuente: Delavari (2005)}  \\
    \toprule
\thead{PP\textsuperscript{*}}
    &   \thead{SP\textsuperscript{**}}
        &   \thead{Conocimiento}
            &   \thead{Mejoras con DM}
                &  \thead{Técnica}          \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{continued on the next page}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\multirow{30}{*}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Evaluación}}
    &   \multirow{30}{*}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Evaluación del Estudiante}} 
        &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
            \item Patrones de éxito o fracaso de estudiantes en un curso en específico
            \item Patrones de éxito de estudiantes con alto rendimiento en un curso en específico
            \end{itemize}  
            &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                \item Agrupamiento de estudiantes con éxito o fracaso en un curso en específico
                \end{itemize}  
                &   \begin{itemize}[\textbullet]
                    \item Clasificación
                    \end{itemize}       \\ 
        \addlinespace
...
< other table rows >
....
%finsegundaparte
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The result is almost the same as before, different is caption simce now the `caption` package is added.

Comment: +1 For a really nice table :) But I still think it'd be useful to show the OP how to use `longtable`, especially if they'd rather not float their table

Comment: @Zarko: As far as I know, traditionally, the position of table captions is *above* tables (hence in the first head for long tables).

Comment: @Bernard, I agree. That is reason why I move it on the top of table in the both proposed solution.

Comment: @Zarko: I'll remove my comment then. I think captions above is especially important in multipage tables.